# How to sort objects by specific fromula using compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, compare, formula

My program should sort the values of persons according to the formula.

```
(Height + Weight)*30% +score40%
```

So the array has the 6 elements we need to sort and output.

#### Issue

I struggle with the calculation formula which actually sorts the values of elements properly using `compareTo(Student o)`

#### Code so far

```
class Student implements  Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;
    private float height, weight, score;

    // constructor getters and setters omitted for brevity

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I am "+name+", my height "+height+", my weight "+weight+", my score "+score);
    }

    public int compareTo(Student  o) {
         if(this.getWeight() > o.getWeight()) {
                          return 1;
                        }
                        else if(this.getWeight() < o.getWeight()) {
                          return -1;
                        }
                        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name="+name+ ",height="+height+",weight="+weight+",score="+score+"]";
    }
}
```

The test:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        Student ps[] = new Student[6];
        ps[0] = new Student("zhangsan", 170, 110, 95);
        ps[1] = new Student("lisi", 168, 120, 75);
        ps[2] = new Student("wangwu", 165, 115, 88);
        ps[3] = new Student("zhaoliu", 172, 121, 90);
        ps[4] = new Student("zhouqi", 160, 100, 85);
        ps[5] = new Student("zhengba", 166, 119, 70);
        System.out.println("array sort before:");
        for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
            ps[i].speak();
        }
        Arrays.sort(ps);  // call sort method
        System.out.println("\narray sort after:");
        for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ps[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your problem actually?  Given you have height weight and score, you could calculate that "whateverScore" by ` (h + w) * 0.3 + s * 0.4`.  Though I shall say it makes more sense to pass comparator into `sort()` instead of using the formula in Student's compareTo

Comment: if(this.getWeight()+this.getHeight()*0.3+getScore()*0.4 > o.getWeight()+this.getHeight()*0.3+getScore()*0.4)  {
                  return 1;
                }
                else if(this.getWeight()+this.getHeight()*0.3+getScore()*0.4  < o.getWeight()+this.getHeight()*0.3+getScore()*0.4 ) {
                  return -1;
                }

Comment: @Adrian Shum i ve tried but still order is incorrect

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around the addition of weight and height.

Comment: And what is your output? You've left off the Student constructor you're using, but in principle your compareTo should work.

Comment: @matt I [removed the boiler-plate like constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72655600/2) (see the code comment) to have focus on the `compareTo`.

Comment: @hc_dev right, but their compare to method should work if they want to sort by weight, I was hope they could describe what the problem with the output is. ie The list is sorted by weight, or when they use their broken formula without the parenthesis the values are random.

Answer (score 0):

#### Given

```
name       |   w |   h |   s | (w+h)*0.3 + s*0.4
zhangsan   | 170 | 110 |  95 | 122.0
lisi       | 168 | 120 |  75 | 116.39999999999999
wangwu     | 165 | 115 |  88 | 119.2
zhaoliu    | 172 | 121 |  90 | 123.89999999999999
zhouqi     | 160 | 100 |  85 | 112.0
zhengba    | 166 | 119 |  70 | 113.5
```

#### Solving advice

Implement the formula first:

```
public Float calculateFormula() {
   return (height + weight) * 0.30 + score * 0.40;
}
```

Use an object-type instead primitive `float` so you can compare the result directly.

Then use it in the `compareTo`:

```
public int compareTo(Student  o) {
  // rest of the comparison, e.g. for null, etc. 
  return this.calculateFormula().compareTo(o.calculateFormula())
}
```